# Stub .prop() with sinon

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinon, konacha

Using Konacha and Sinon.js. I have the following Javascript in Coffee Script (simplified for clarity):

```
if $('#payment_cc').prop('checked')
  console.log 'checked'
else
  console.log 'not checked'
```

I have been trying to stub `$('#payment_cc').prop('checked')` in the test spec, but still couldn't get it done. I used `spy`, `stub` methods in sinon, or `$('#payment_cc').click()`, but couldn't simulate the DOM. Been cracking my head for hours. Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't simulate the DOM?"

Comment: @Narong couldn't simulate the `$('#payment_cc')` to `check`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check/uncheck a checkbox, it's done like this:

```
$("#payment_cc").prop("checked", true); //check
$("#payment_cc").prop("checked", false); //uncheck
```

If you're trying to see if the element is checked or not, it's done like this:

```
$("#payment_cc").is(":checked") //returns true or false
```

Answer (score -1):

### Use:

```
if ($('#payment_cc').is(":checked"))
```

#### or

```
if ($('#payment_cc')[0].checked)
```

to check if a checkbox is checked.